# Print x for every evaluation using Nelder Mead method from scipy.optimize

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I have a problem when using scipy.optimize.minimize from python 2.7. What I wanna print out is the x value for every function evaluation. However, the result it returned only gave the x value corresponding to the iteration. Is there a way to do so? Thanks a lot!

Here is the code

```
import math
import sys
from scipy import optimize
f_NMO=open('output_NMO.txt','w')

def rosenbr(x):
    x1 = x[0]
    x2 = x[1]
    f = pow((x2-pow(x1,2)),2)/0.01+pow((x1-1),2)
    return f

xi2 = [5,5]
def cb1(r1):
    f_val1=rosenbr(r1)
    global best1
    best1 = 300
    global ctn1
    ctn1 += 1
    if f_val1 < best1:
        best1 = f_val1
    f_NMO.write("%.0f" % ctn1 + " , fun=" + "%.8f" % f_val1  + " , best=" + "%.8f" % best1  + " , xa=" + "%.8f" % r1[0] + " , xb=" + "%.8f" % r1[1] + '\n')

r1=optimize.minimize(rosenbr, xi2, method='Nelder-Mead', tol=1e-6, callback=cb1, options={'maxfev': 5000, 'disp': True, 'return_all': True})
```

Comment: Maybe showing us your code will allow us to better understand your question and help you.

Comment: I ve already add a pic

Comment: @FredFederico, please copy-and-paste your code, do not attach code in images. Images make it unnecessarily difficult for us to run and test your code.

Comment: Your function gets x - print from it.

Comment: @JonCuster, sorry can u specify it a little bit, which x do u mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
def rosenbr(x):
    x1 = x[0]
    x2 = x[1]
    f = pow((x2-pow(x1,2)),2)/0.01+pow((x1-1),2)
    print("x = ", x)    # <<<<< here
    return f
```

Comment: Could you explain how/why your code works? That'll enable the OP and others to understand and apply your methods (where applicable) elsewhere. Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/284827) and liable to be deleted. — [During review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10761937).